# повесить\забрать класс active на JS

Tags: javascript, menu

Господа, задача простая: повесить\забрать класс с массива ссылок. Нашёл код, где  не пойму какую роль играет в while **el**

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("maneMenu");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].onclick = function() {
    let el = elements[0];
    while (el) {
      // вот здесь туплю
      if (el.tagName === "A") {
        el.classList.remove("active");
      }
      el = el.nextSibling;
    }
    this.classList.add("active");
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar wrapper_menu">
  <a class="maneMenu" href="#"></a>
  <a class="maneMenu" href="#"></a>
  <a class="maneMenu" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Можете подсказать другие варианты реализации на JS?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("maneMenu");
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {/*прокручиваем в цикле все элементы*/
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {  /*при клике на элемент 
 */
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      elements[i].classList.remove('active'); /*удаляем у всех class active*/
    }
    this.classList.add('active');/*добавляем class active по которому кликнули */
  })
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar wrapper_menu">
  <a class="maneMenu" href="#">1111</a>
  <a class="maneMenu" href="#">2222</a>
  <a class="maneMenu" href="#">3333</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Как это отвечает на поставленный вопрос? Да и хотя бы объяснил бы что в коде происходит :-/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, мне кажется в прямом смысле и отвечает

Comment: как отвечает на вопрос "какую роль играет в while **el**" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хотел сделать два варианта, но не получилось,  второй вариант переретер  первый, подскажи, как одним ответом два варианта реализовать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, прочитай, что у него в вопросе последнюю строчку

Comment: И ни на один из них, ты не ответил. На первый напрямую, а на второй ни разу не сказал что ты там творишь в этом своем куске кода.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я буду рад, если ты подробнее мне укажешь, что да, как....

Comment: Почему **я** должен подробно указывать, что да как **у тебя**? Ты не можешь пояснить свой код для человека и для остальных, кто придет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,  добавляет и удаляет класс у того элемента на который кликает,

Comment: Ты можешь пояснения хотя бы в виде комментариев написать в самом коде?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,  кастати  в самом примете реализаван мой первый ваниант ответа

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не надо мен считать ханжой, я собирался, но когда, мой второй вариант ответа перетер первый, не могу оба варианта отправить и описать)))  подскажи, как в одном ответе два варианта написать

Comment: нажимаешь "Вставить фрагмент кода", заполняешь его, вставляешь..... потом ставишь курсор внизу...... нажимаешь enter... и  проделываешь опять операцию по вставке фрагмента кода